# upshot validation rules

Tags: breeze, upshot

Have someone a Url or some example of how to create custom Rules for the metadata section of upshot.js

For example a rule that the element did't already exist in the localDatabase observable array.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott and Microsoft team says they are going to not continue (by now) with the upshot.js development.

I´m going to stop studying this library.

Tx

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty [good discussion on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238855/current-status-of-upshot-js) of the Upshot situation and alternatives. The net of it is that Upshot has been abandoned and, fortunately, there are some good choices of libraries out there, including BreezeJS, Ember, and JayData